# escaping single quote from json data no solution working

Tags: php, json

I'm getting json data from a website.. but in the data there is single quote that causing the problem. what will you suggest me to do i already tried str_replace is not working please help

Here is code

```
$string=file_get_contents('http://website');
$string=str_replace("'", "\'", $string);//not working
$json=json_decode($string);
foreach($json as $p)
{
$query="INSERT INTO abc(id,
name,
address,
address2,
storeID,
) VALUES('$p->id',
'$p->name',
'$p->address',
'$p->address2',
'$p->storeID',
)";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

if I use str_replace this error comes

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Please consider using Prepared Statements with PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing a single quote with a single quote. Instead, you want:

```
$string = str_replace("'", '"', $string);
```

Also, you must not insert user input into SQL statements. Either use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [encode](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) the user input.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = str_replace("'", '"', $string);
```

do this way